# Issue with getJSON Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

i have a question

This making me crazy

I write a barcode scanner witch check data from json.

The script works fine but

After the while loop i want to get a error alert message if the getjson request dont match with the scanned barcode.

That means if the code dont get into the `if(myshopdata.order.reference==barcode)`

But every time i put the error alert `alert("Code cannot be found");` in my code, the error message comes long before the getjson message.

I know that getJSON is async. and try the same with ajax call , but its to slow it tested it.

Can anyone help me how i solve this in my Code?

The error message is the only thing is missing in my script

This is my script

Comment: `$.getJSON is async`... so your code is behaving correctly. You need to add `success` and `error` callbacks to manage this.

Comment: Yes i know but i dont know how i can use it in my example code :(

Comment: Check from here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

Following comments... see updated answer using `$.when.apply()` approach.

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan", function(evt){

    if (evt.success == true) {
      //successful scan
      var barcode = evt.codedata;                             

      //Get numbers of Orders
      $.getJSON("http://www.testurl.de/api/orders/?ws_key=TEEUQWL9J76LFQE&output_format=JSON", function(data){                        

          var order =  JSON.stringify(data);   
          var orderdata =JSON.parse(order); 
          var ordercount = Object.keys(orderdata.orders).length;

          var queries = [];
          var result = 0;
          var i = 0;

          while(i <= ordercount)
          {
            queries.push(

                $.getJSON("http://www.testurl.de/api/orders/"+i+"?ws_key=TEZQFW41L9J76LFQE&output_format=JSON", function(data){

                  var shopdata = JSON.stringify(data);               
                  var myshopdata =JSON.parse(shopdata);
                  result++; // Increment results counter
                  sweetAlert("Code will be checkd", "Please wait","info");

                  if(myshopdata.order.reference == barcode)
                    addcode(myshopdata.order.reference,myshopdata.order.associations.order_rows[0].product_name,myshopdata.order.total_paid_tax_incl,myshopdata.order.associations.order_rows[0].product_id);                         

                });
            );

            i++;
          } //end of while loop 

          // When all the getJSON calls have completed
          $.when.apply($, queries).done(function() {

              if(!result) // check results
                console.log('No orders found');
          });

      }); //end of get json       

    }//end of event listener if 
    else
      sweetAlert("Hoppla", "Woltest du nicht gerade scannen? :) ");

},false);//end of event listener
```